# Internationalize enums used in form:select

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, internationalization

I have a question on how to internatiolize my form:select options. I got to the part that I can show the internationalization in the form: select options but it saves the message code and not the translation.

*JSP*

```
                     <form:select path="mutation">
                        <sun2:forEach items="${mutationOptions}" var="option">
                            <form:option value="${option.messageCode}">
                                <bookkeeping:message code="${option.messageCode}"/>
                            </form:option>
                        </sun2:forEach>
                    </form:select>
```

Of course it's logical that it saves the message code and not the translation because I call option.messageCode in the form:option value but I can't figure out how to do it differently. I can't put a message tag into the option value.

*ENUM*

```
public enum InvoiceMutationEnum {
INTERNET_BANKING("mutation.internet.banking"), BANK_TRANSFER("mutation.transfer"), COLLECTION("mutation.collection"),
MISCELLANEOUS("mutation.miscellaneous");

private String messageCode;

InvoiceMutationEnum(final String messageCode) {
    this.messageCode = messageCode;
}

public String getMessageCode() {
    return messageCode;
}
```

}

What I want is to save the value of message.properties into the database instead of the message code.

What is the best way to approach this?

Kind Regards,

Coos Wolff

Comment: In general, if it's for saving in the database rather than presentation, then you should save the code, not the internationalized text. You can keep a separate lookup table that will have the codes and the translations, and can be joined together with the codes for display purposes (or if you're displaying through a Java client, use the properties file as is).

Comment: @RealSkeptic thanks for the clarification. I thought for unexplaneable reasons that you don't want to save the codes. But I think I shouldn't see that as a bad thing.